# How to write a code to print the maximum of entered values?

Tags: python, math

I am writing a code to print sum, average, maximum and minimum.
I could not figure out how to print the maximum
this is the code. it should only accept 20 entries

```
 a=0
 b=0
 c=0
 d=0
 while a!=20:
        x=eval(input("Enter number: "))
        b+=x
        if x>c:
               c=x
               a+=1
        if x<x:
               d=x
avg=b/2
print(b,avg,c,d)
```

is the method i am using wrong?

Comment: What have you tried and researched so far?

Comment: use max() func on list? please do some research or at least read rules before posting this type of questions

Comment: with the same method you printed the minimum but in reverse I would say :)

Comment: @klausD. I have tried to reverse the code i used to print the minimum but it did not work

Comment: @VladimirVishnevskyi sorry I am still a beginner. it is not a list, it is a group of entries

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev I did as you can see but it did not work

Comment: OK, so there is missing information here, it seems that your code will work (count correctly 20 inputs) only if the next number is bigger than the one before (if not endless loop). You should never use single letter variable names like "t", "m" etc. it is very bad practice and your code is unclear because of that. On a separate note, you are just dividing the sum by 2, this is not average, average is sum divided by total items/ numbers/ members of your input. If you have 5 numbers with sum 15, your average will be 15/3. You should fix the above and edit your question with all information.

Comment: + this condition here "if x<x:" how do you expect x to be smaller than x when both are x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation based on your code and the information available.

Basically, you create all your variables on top of the file, then loop until 5 numbers are entered (in this example) and do the necessary operations to calculate total, average, max and min values.

The minimum value is trickier, there is a workaround in the code below, you could also add the `counter == 0` check in your `if/elif` block for minimum with a little help from the `or` operator.

```
total = 0
average = 0
maximum = 0
minimum = 0
counter = 0

while counter < 5:
    input_number = int(input("Enter number: "))
    total += input_number

    if counter == 0:
        minimum = input_number

    if input_number > maximum:
        maximum = input_number
    elif input_number < minimum:
        minimum = input_number

    counter += 1

average = total / 5

print(total, average, maximum, minimum)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I was not expecting you to write the whole code from the beginning. I am learning on my own that's why I do not have a clear understanding of most the basic concepts. on the part about the average, I admit it was pure stupidity.
I will make sure my future questions be more precise

Comment: @MohammedBurhan, that's quite alright, you can do just fine learning on your own, in fact I think most of the programmers nowadays are like that, IT/programming school/uni can teach you limited things and the rest you should research on your own, just be careful what online courses you are taking and the docs you read (do a bit of research before starting new course/ tutorial).